# AppleScript : set dropdown menu value in safari

Tags: drop-down-menu, safari, applescript, dropdown

I can't get applescript to set the dropdown menu in safari

HTML :

```
value="WSelectionString">Please select a option</option>
<option value="0">option 1</option>
<option value="1">option2</option>
<option value="2">option3</option>
<option value="3">option4</option>
<option value="4">option5</option>
```

Script :

```
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('0.3.7InfoInspector.1.1.3').value = '1'" in document 1
end tell
```

Update : Another page with the same issue

```
<div id="disOnly" style="">
                            TEXT here.

                                <br><br>
                                TEXT1: <select name="0.7.3.1.1.1">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Action 1 Lock</option>
<option value="1">Action 2</option></select>
                                <br><br>


                                Text 2  <select name="0.3.3.1.3.1"><option value="WString">Please select a option</option>
<option value="0">TEXT/option>
<option value="1">TEXT2</option>

                                <br><br>

                            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tell application "Safari"
  activate
  tell current tab of window 1
    do JavaScript "document.getElementById('0.3.7InfoInspector.1.1.3').value = '1'"
  end tell
end tell
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, no error on AppleScript replies, the dropbox menu is selected (highlighted on safari) but unfortunately the text is not selected

Comment: Is the value you're setting definitely one of the available options? Is the form  somewhere public you can show me?

Comment: I just updated the HTML , is that because I have to mention the option text in Applescript?

Comment: No, the value is all you need. Can you post the html for the whole select element?

Comment: I just realised it's work with other website when I have a ID, but on this case I don't so document.getElementById is not working, tried document.getElementsByName instead but no result